# taking javascript from onload and moving it somewhere else

Tags: javascript

I'm following a tutorial for creating a custom WYSIWYG editor. I understand PHP fairly well, but am pretty new to Javasript.

The code works great, but I'm going to be using the code as a php include on a Dreamweaver template, so I don't have access to the Body tag (Unless I change all 1000 pages).

It uses the code:

```
<body onLoad="iFrameOn();">
```

to call this function:

```
function iFrameOn(){
    richTextField.document.designMode = 'On';
}
```

which refers to this piece of HTML:

```
<iframe name="richTextField" 
        id="richTextField" 
        style="border:#000000 1px solid; width:700px; height:300px;">
</iframe>
```

How would I go about calling `iFrameOn()` if not using onload in the body?
I did a little research, and I though I could just call it at the beginning of my include in a  `<script></script>` tag, but no go... 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Either move it to the end of `<body>` or use jQuery's `$(document).ready()`-function.